# Table is not appearing in the book class

Tags: tables, books

I am trying to put a table in a document and I am using the book class. I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4 paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{subcaption, bm, float, color}
%\usepackage[ inner =1.5in , outer =1in ]{ geometry }
\usepackage{multicol}

%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} %for \toprule \midrule
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{|c | c | c | c |}
            \toprule
            x & y & w & z
            \\
            \midrule
            a & b & abc & abc \\
            a & b & abc & abc\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{fancy caption 1}
        \label{table 1 a}
    \end{table}
    \columnbreak
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{|c | c | c | c |}
            \toprule
            x & y & w & z
            \\
            \midrule
            a & b & abc & abc \\
            a & b & abc & abc\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{fancy caption 2}
        \label{table 1 b}
    \end{table}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

I have tried many ways and searched through many questions such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555699), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405774),  [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30016), [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2516), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405774) and many more.

But nothing worked out for me. The table is missing from the document. I have compiled at least three times after I checked the solution. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your example is not very minimal (do you need all those packages to show the problem?) and generates an error `! Extra }, or forgotten $.` but when that is fixed, also note that `multicol` does not support floats.

Comment: LaTeX does warn you `Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside \`multicols'  environment!.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle fixed it. Also, I removed the unnecessary packages from the MWE. Please help me now.

Comment: see Don H's answer, also note that you can't really use `|` vertical rules with booktabs, see the package doc it makes vertical rules unusable by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use floats (i.e., `table` and `figure`) inside a `multicols` environment (in fact, if you look at the log output from LaTeX, you should see a warning:

```
Floats and marginpars not allowed inside ‘multicols’ environment!
```

You can use `table*` and `figure*` in a `multicols` although that's probably not what you're trying to do.

Since you're using the `[h]` option on your `table` you can probably get what you want by using the `captions` package and writing, e.g.,

```
\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c | c | c | c |}
        \toprule
        x & y & w & z
        \\
        \midrule
        a & b & abc & abc \\
        a & b & abc & abc\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{fancy caption 2}
    \label{table 1 b}
\end{minipage}\end{center}
```

The `minipage` environment is there to make sure that the `tabular` and its caption aren't separated. It's enclosed in a `center` environment so it gets treated as displayed material (otherwise it would get a paragraph indent) and then the `\centering` inside the `minipage` is to make sure the `tabular` environment is centered since the outer `center` environment doesn't apply to the `minipage`. You'll probably want to wrap all of this up in a `\newenvironment` definition.

**Update based on further information from original poster**

If the objective is to put two tabulars side by side, you don't need the `multicols` environment at all. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
       \begin{tabular}{|c | c | c | c |}
            \toprule
            x & y & w & z
            \\
            \midrule
            a & b & abc & abc \\
            a & b & abc & abc\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{fancy caption 1}
        \label{table 1 a}\end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \begin{tabular}{|c | c | c | c |}
            \toprule
            x & y & w & z
            \\
            \midrule
            a & b & abc & abc \\
            a & b & abc & abc\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{fancy caption 2}
        \label{table 1 b}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

(note: untested code)

Comment: Don, I have tried using ```table*``` as I have listed the questions visited before asking the question. But I didn't get the desired result. The table appeared on another page which is not desirable for me. Also, they appeared vertically. I need them to be aligned side by side.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do. You're working too hard at this. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the above code worked for me. Thank you very much! Don